# jQuery JSON parsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Need some advise on what I am doing wrong during client JSON parsing...  Tips and comments welcome my code returns nothing. Debugger doesn't show anything useful either.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        var htmlString = "test";
    $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=functionName&q=%23csharp", functionName);

    function functionName(data) {

            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            htmlString += item.content + "<br>";
            });
            $('#test').html(htmlString);
        }

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: If you `console.log(data);` right after your success message what comes back? Can you post that? Looking at the URL it looks like a function is returned.

Comment: Can you post the response from the service (using Fiddler or a similar tool)?

Comment: Added console and here is the result:

Comment: document is ready
Object { results=[15], max_id=71266848888467460, more...}
a is undefined
f(a=undefined, c=function(), d=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 16)
functionName(data=Object { results=[15], max_id=71266848888467460, more...})testjson.html (line 13)
f(e=Object { url="http://search.twitter.c...3csharp&_=1305826953953", isLocal=true, more...}, f=[Object { results=[15], max_id=71266848888467460, more...}, "success", Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}])jquery.min.js (line 16)
g(a=200, c="success", l=undefined, m=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 18)
g(a=load , c=undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't specify the name of your callback function. jQuery will do that for you.  The function that handles the JSONP request is specially constructed to allow you to use your function as normal and to provide other useful features.

Do `callback=?` instead:

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=%23csharp", functionName);
```

---

The other problem is with this:

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
```

You're iterating over `data.items`.  This doesn't exist in the response.  You then ask for `item.content`.  This doesn't exist either.  I don't know what JSON you're designing your code for, because it's not the JSON twitter sends.

Comment: Thanks, corrected that. I actually added the method in testing but tried not adding it and just now with =? and no results still.

Comment: @Tom See edit. You need to work out what you want from the returned data, and follow its structure. Your code bears no relation to the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I was digging in the wrong object which was null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$.ajax()` method instead to get more granular feedback on the status of your request.

Comment: I used that insted of getJSON and it gives me less info.

Comment: Now I am understanding some client crap. not item but results: 
data Object { results=[15], max_id=71271710921465860, more...}

$.each(data.results, function(i,results){
htmlString += results.text + "<br>";
});

Little strange to me. Thanks for your assistance in leading me in the correct route.

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the callback in the url:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23csharp

Comment: That will cause the AJAX request to fail due to the same-origin policy. The OP needs to signal to jQuery to handle this as a JSONP request.

Comment: Duh, forgot about that.  Thanks.